# hard bounce back notification not being received immediately

Tags: exim, email-bounces

We have an exim server setup and configured. The email is being sent by godaddy relay server. In Section: ROUTERSTART, we have specified the following:

> send_to_smart_host: 
>   driver = manualroute 
>   route_list = !+local_domains #godaddy relay server# 
>   transport = remote_smtp

We have already made the below setting in exim configuration:
return_path_remove = false

When there is a soft bounce (e.g.: mail quota exceeded), we receive an almost instance bounce back notification email on the email address specified in the return path (while sending the email).
However, when there is a hard bounce (e.g.: email or domain does not exist), we don't receive any bounce back notification.

Can someone please let me know if we are missing an exim configuration? Or if anything needs to be done while sending email?

We use PHPMailer to send email.